# Reading Web Traffic source from Google analytic code(Cookie = __utmz) Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to get  "Direct", "Organic", "Refferal" and "Paid Search" Traffic information.
I am reading Web Traffic info using following post.

[Get the referrer, paid/natural and keywords for the current visitor with Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631830/get-the-referrer-paid-natural-and-keywords-for-the-current-visitor-with-google)

I am getting following values "__utmz" from cookie

Organic : 2432541.8749459613.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=merit.com

Direct:  2432541.8749459613.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)

Refferal: 2432541.8749459613.1.1.utmcsr=xyz.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/xyz.aspx

**Question 1:**

As mentioned inf the post vals.utmcmd parameter should return medium name from which traffic is came to our site. For direct web traffic value of "utmcmd " is null.

What value should I read to get traffic info? (utmccn?)

**Question 2:**
Since I can not get Paid traffic before going into production,
What can be cookie value for "__utmz" for paid search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1) "Direct", "Organic", "Refferal" and "Paid Search" are medium, so use `utmccn`

Question 2) Add parameters like this to your URL to simulate a cpc campaign :

```
?utm_source=test-source&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=test-campaign
```