# How to find the medium and search keyword using referrer - Web Analytics?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, google-analytics, uri

I have taken the referrer using the `document.referrer` from DOM. I had found some of the parameters like(port, source, host, etc.) using [parseUri function](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseUri).

Now how can I find out the medium and search keyword using the referrer or any idea about how google analytics manipulating `_utmz` cookie?

Any idea will be greatful.

Comment: Can you add some examples in your question ? Some inputs and their expected outputs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the referrer, paid/natural and keywords for the current visitor with Google Analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631830/get-the-referrer-paid-natural-and-keywords-for-the-current-visitor-with-google)