# Google Analytics missing __utmz cookie

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I have universal analytics installed on my website, and want to parse the `__utmz` cookie to get referral info. However, I never see this cookie set.

Has something changed? Any reason this isn't set?

I do see the `_ga` cookie when I browse my site, and I see the `__utmz` cookie in my browser cache if I go to *other* sites.

I checked out the docs, and don't see any reference to this changing recently, so a bit stumped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Universal Analytics doesn't create any __utm* cookies.

However, you can use Universal Analytics code (analytics.js) AND the traditional code (ga.js) simultaneously on your site.  This will allow you to populate your UA profile and scrape the values from __utmz.

Comment: ah! sneaky.. yes that sounds like it could work. Not sure how long google are suppoering ga.js tho.

Comment: If you're concerned about Google dropping ga.js, just make a copy of it and reference it locally.

Comment: updating your implementation would be a better idea.  once google drops ga.js, you never know if ga.js will be referencing outdated api endpoints

Answer (score 4):

It seems like with Universal Analytics, this cookie has disappeared, and you only get a single _ga cookie.

Source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage

Also mentioned here: [How to get the referrer, paid/natural and keywords for the current visitor in PHP with new Google Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927924/how-to-get-the-referrer-paid-natural-and-keywords-for-the-current-visitor-in-ph)

Also given that analytics is primarily a tool to collect aggregated information, I couldn't find (and I doubt) that there is any way to query GA to get this info back, given the `_ga` cookie.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own cookie and store the query string parameters that google analytics use (utm_campaign and etc).
See this project as example:
https://github.com/dm-guy/utm-alternative

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get *utmz cookie* along with your universal analytics js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```