# Parse user information with Google universal analytics client side

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is there a way to parse user information from Analytics, like referral, paid traffic, campaign, and so. With the old Analytics code it was as simple as [parsing the cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631830/get-the-referrer-paid-natural-and-keywords-for-the-current-visitor-with-google), but the new Analytics system does not save the user information in a cookie.

Reading the documentation I'd manage to get the client id, but that's all:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  console.log(tracker.get('clientId'));
});
```

Is there a way to do this in javascript?, there was a [suggestion of using both old a the new system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604715/google-analytics-missing-utmz-cookie) so I can populate the cookie, but that seems a bit ugly to me.

Comment: Did you find an answer?